# Determining errors in latitude and longitude?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates

I have a large database that contains at grade railroad crossings (railroad crossings that intersect roadways). Many of these contain incorrect latitude and longitude values. I need to determine which coordinates are incorrect without entering them all in google maps (there are thousands of crossings). These coordinated need to be accurate, but an error up to 200ft is okay.

Comment: Can you define what incorrect is? Are there multiple types of incorrect?

Comment: @risail the latitude and longitude values are incorrect

Comment: I don't understand why this post has been voted as unclear.  I believe it should be reopened.

Comment: I edited it while logged out so it shows anonymous but it should be more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Spatial Analyst Extension is not useful here (you list it in your question tags).  Ordinarily I'd suggest the [snap points to lines tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/snapping-points-to-lines.htm).  However, in this case you need to snap to the intersections of two different layers. You can automate this process by doing something like this:

1. Create a layer of your road and rail crossing points by intersecting your road lines with your rail lines.
2. Use the [Snap Tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/snap.htm) to then snap your crossings points to the output of step 1 above.
3. Intersect your snapped points with the output of step 1 to give the coincident points an id and thereby identify the ones which lay outside your snap tolerance (the ones with a null value for the intersect id).  You can then either repeat the process with a bigger tolerance, or edit the outliers by hand.